# Jekyll include content from another collection

Tags: jekyll

Hope someone can help me, I'm really stuck working with collections.

At the moment I have two setup, :guides :places.

What I'd like to do is setup a place once in the places collection and include attributes like location, website, image etc.

Then I want to be able to reference the place in the guide collection. My guide could be coffee shops so I can reference the place one and pull in all the content. A place might be in a few different guides so I'll be able to update the image of the place and automatically update all the guides.

I've tried using the following:-

```
{% include_relative coffee-shop.md %}
```

But it tries to find it within the same collection? Not sure how I can get out of the current collection and grab this from the place collection?

Any advice would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Working with your:

```
collections:
  places:
    ...
  guides:
    ...
```

You'll get the matching data in `site.places` and `site.guides`.  If you just want to insert the content, you'd have to do something like:

```
{% assign place = site.places | where: "name","Toronto" | first %}
{{ place.content }}
```